# What function do i use to run code when ASP.NET starts up?

Tags: asp.net

I want to run some basic checks when my ASP.NET server goes up. Mostly simple things like does the db exist, am i missing any bins, etc. What function do i use to call my code?

Comment: Do you want a web application to do this or something on the system side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use the application_start event on Global.asax

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't waste my time on any of these things. Are they likely to be problems more than once a year or less? Instead, I'd just make sure my code gave good exception messages when or if these problems arise.

Comment: What if he's building an ASP.Net application he wants to sell?

Comment: Then I wouldn't waste my time on these. I'd make sure my installer installed everything; I'd make sure it had a Repair feature; I might separately package the Installation Verification step called in the installer so it could be run as a diagnostic; and I'd make sure to produce excellent exception messages and other diagnostics.

Comment: What if i want to find the problem ASAP instead of eventually ;)

Comment: Then you could periodically run the Installation Verification Procedure as I suggested. I would be interested to know under what circumstances that ever fails after the first good install. I bet it never does, absent some idiot who deletes the bin directory. You need good runtime exception logging, messages, etc. in any case.

Comment: There is no installer ATM, i am basically passing this around to a few guys (typically w/o source). There is only a few lines added. Exceptions work but then the users would have to do stuff before its thown.

Comment: I don't think we're understanding each other, and I thought you were talking a production site. Please edit your question to clarify what you're trying to accomplish, what kind of users, how distributed, what version of ASP.NET and Windows, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**WebActivator**](https://bitbucket.org/davidebbo/webactivator/wiki/Home), which you can get as a NuGet package.
WebActivator can be used to run arbitrary code at application start, even declared in other assemblies.

It's a nice way to decouple some logic (ie. DB initialization) from web project (your web project shouldn't have a direct dependency on DB access code).

WebActivator is often used by other NuGet packages to run their own initialization without explicit code in Global.asax.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx) on MSDN.